# Kendo TreeView with remote data binding not showing the children

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, treeview

I am trying to display a folder structure via Kendo TreeView...If I insert the items in the view, it works fine. When I try to do it with remote data binding, it is showing only the parent nodes and no options to expand is there...even though the folder has other Folder/files inside. Here is the code:

```
Html.Kendo().TreeView()
            .Name("DownloadTreeView")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Read(read => read.Action("GetFiles", "DownloadSettings"))
            )
            .ExpandAll(true)
            .Render();


public JsonResult GetFiles(string path)
    {
        const string StartDirectory = @"L:\dsms\assets";
        path = path ?? StartDirectory;
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(path).Select(file =>
            new DownloadTreeViewVM
            {
                Id = file,
                HasChildren = false,
                Name = Path.GetFileName(file)
            });

        var directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path).Select(dir =>
            new DownloadTreeViewVM
            {
                Id = dir,
                HasChildren = Directory.GetFiles(dir).Any() || Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Any(),
                Name = Path.GetFileName(dir)
            });

        var result = files.ToList();
        result.AddRange(directories);
        result = result.OrderBy(x => !x.HasChildren).ToList();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass your parameter as nullable string and rename it to id try this:

```
public JsonResult GetFiles(string? id)
{
  //then do your stuff
}
```

and remove ExpandAll(true) from the treeview

Comment: thank you for the answer. Actually I did this: hasChildren instead of "HasChildren"...now it works...